# Git Commit message with two change IDs

Tags: git, gerrit

I have for my change the commit message

> Change-Id: If5c1cc146c8d6ee9720954b2c1f1ec0f04e123af
>
> Bug: xxxxx
>
> Change-Id: I0401da871158d21ee9a2dd55d282a1f5f9281cee

When I click the second change ID the change remains. But for the fisrt cahnge ID it goes to another change.

I want to make a commit message with only change ID

> Change-Id: I0401da871158d21ee9a2dd55d282a1f5f9281cee

But when I push with this changeID, there is always a new commit with a new change. How can I change the commit message with just one Change ID which is the second one. As per my understanding the third line  is taken as the Change Id. But why the last line for change ID is taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  git commit --amend
it will let you change the last commit message and you can even change the change-ID

Comment: I get this error when I push with one change ID! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (missing Change-Id in commit e footer)

Comment: again do git commit --amend and also add change ID at the bottom of the commit i.e footer like this  Change-Id: If5c1cc146c8d6ee9720954b2c1f1ec0f04e123af

Bug: xxxxx

Change-Id: If5c1cc146c8d6ee9720954b2c1f1ec0f04e123af

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have already pushed the first commit (with the two Change-Ids + the Bug-Id) to Gerrit, right? So just use the Gerrit UI to edit the commit message removing the first two lines (the Change-Id + the empty line).